# Why does reading from a pipe give garbage values?

Tags: c, pipe, system-calls

```
// Some code for initialization

int fd[2];
pipe(fd);
int k = fork();

if (k == 0) {    // Child
    dup2(fd[1], fileno(stdout));
    execl("someExecutable", NULL);    // The executable just printfs one line
}
else if (k > 0) {    // Parent
    wait(&status);
    while (read(fd[0], buffer, 1) > 0) {
        printf("%s", buffer);
    }
}
```

I omitted error checking.

First, if my executable has `printf("some line\n");`, my output on screen looks like `s?9o?9m?9e?9 ?9l?9i?9n?9e?9`. Why are there these random characters in between?

Second, my reading never ends. The read end of the pipe should've closed when the executable ended right?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure `buffer` will be a null-terminated string?

Comment: Let's see the pipe initialization code.

Comment: This is one thing that confuses me. Whether it is null-terminated or not. Does o not come directly after s in the pipe's buffer? How could garbage values get inserted in between?

Comment: I hope, i am not missing something here.excel() takes the arguments which represent a new executable image, not a function call e.g., excel("/usr/bin/ls", '-al", NULL); to execute an ls command to print all the file attributes in long mode. refer to http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve for such details.

Comment: Yes my execl statement is executing another source code file, which contains one print function.

Comment: The child closes its write end of the pipe when it terminates, but the parent never does.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Is this advice, or the reason for the while loop not exiting?

Comment: It is the reason your while loop doesn't exit.  *All* write ends of the pipe must be closed.  This means the parent must close fd[1] before it starts the loop, or the read from fd[0] will block indefinitely.

Comment: Ah I see thank you. I did indeed thought it was only the child's write end that I needed to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing binary data. The following

```
 while (read(fd[0], buffer, 1) > 0) {
    printf("%s", buffer);
}
```

Will print until it gets a NULL ie '\0'. Try this instead

```
 while (read(fd[0], buffer, 1) > 0) {
    printf("%.*s", 1, buffer);
}
```

This code might help illustrate the point about printf and null terminated strings...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
  srand(time(NULL));
  size_t n = 0;
  //First we create some random data. 
  //Lets assume this is our binary stream
  char *str_cpy = malloc(1024);
  n = 0;
  while(n++ < 1024) {
    str_cpy[n] = rand() % 255;
  } 
  //We have a known string we want to print
  const char *str = "foobar";
  printf("%s\n", str); 
  memcpy(str_cpy, str, 6);//Ooops: forgot to copy the null terminator 
  size_t str_len = strlen(str_cpy);
  // This is unlikely to print 6
  printf("%zu\n", str_len);
  //This is undefined behavior
  printf("%s\n", str_cpy);
  free(str_cpy);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: But I don't understand why garbage values get put in between my characters. I would understand if it printed "some linegarbagechars" since it is not null-terminated.

Comment: @fossdeep - you get garbage characters in between because each time you call `printf("%s",buffer)`, the function `printf` will read from the buffer one byte at a time and write to `stdout` until it finds a `'\0'`.  This could be immediately, or 1000 bytes later, or it could throw a segmentation fault for attempting to read past the end of your readable memory.  In your case, it looks like you are "lucky" enough to have '\0' just a few bytes past the intended value.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a (pointer to) null-terminated string to `%s` format specifier in `printf()`.

To print one character, using `%c` is good.

```
while (read(fd[0], buffer, 1) > 0) {
    printf("%c", *buffer);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why this is different than printf("%s", buffer) if buffer is only allowed to read/store 1 character in it at a time. Or does buffer at one iteration possibly contain more characters?

Answer (score 0):

If your buffer is declared as char buffer, then pass a pointer to it in read(), if it is declare as buffer[], then you may want to pass the size as the parameter instead of 1, as you are already checking for the status for read() which should return the number of bytes read, if successful. Now change printf("%c"...) or printf("%s"...), accordingly.